# Issue with codeigniter view , add, insert, update

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Tried example from this [codeigniter view, add, update and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509140/codeigniter-view-add-update-and-delete), but I get error.

Controller:

```
<?php
class Siejimas extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    session_start();
  $this->load->view('main_view');
  $this->load->Model("siejimas_model");
  $pavadinimas = $this->input->post("pavadinimas"); // get the data from a form submit
 // $pavadinimas = $this->xss->clean();
  $error = $this->siejimas_model->addRecord($pavadinimas);
  if(!$error) {
     $results = $this->siejimas_model->selectAll();
     $data['parduotuve'] = $results->result();
     $this->load->view("siejimas_view", $data);
  } else {
     $this->load->view("error");
  }
}
}
?>
```

Model :

```
    <?php
    class Siejimas_model extends CI_Model {
      function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
      }
      function addRecord($pavadinimas) {
        $this->db->set("pavadinimas", $pavadinimas);
        $this->db->insert("parduotuve");
        return $this->db->_error_number(); 
      }
      function updateRecord($pavadinimas) {
        $this->db->set("pavadinimas", $pavadinimas);
        $this->db->update("parduotuve");
      }
      function deleteRecord($pavadinimas) {
        $this->db->where("pavadinimas", $pavadinimas);
        $this->db->delete("parduotuve");
      }
      function selectRecord($pavadinimas) {
        $this->db->select("pavadinimas, id");
        $this->db->from("parduotuve");
        $this->db->where("pavadinimas", $pavadinimas);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $this->db->result();
      }
      function selectAll() {
         $this->db->select("pavadinimas");
         $this->db->from("parduotuve");
         return $this->db->get();
      }
    }
    ?>
```

View:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Parduotuvės pavadiniams</td>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($parduotuve as $row): ?>
 <tr><td><?php echo $row->pavadinimas; ?></td></tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
```

and my table name is parduotuove and what thing what I want to update, add or insert is pavadinimas.

Getting errors :

```
 A PHP Error was encountered
 Severity: Notice
 Message: Undefined variable: parduotuve
 Filename: views/siejimas_view.php
Line Number: 5
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: views/siejimas_view.php
Line Number: 5
```

Maybe somebody know how to fix this problem? example in link was good, but where was too much name and Names and I Cant understand clearly which I should edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ProbLem is in your Model selectAll() function.

put the table name
in
return $this->db->get('TABLE NAME');
OR
return  $this->db->from("parduotuve");

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\svetaine\application\controllers\redagavimas.php on line 12

Comment: or change 
function selectAll() {
         $sql="select pavadinimas from parduotuve";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
         return $query;
      }